# VB6 - Invalid Column name with Insert query

Tags: sql-server, database, vb6

I'm testing a small program to write some data to a SQL Server 2008 database. This is the code:

```
Dim MyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim st1 As Integer

Set MyConn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
       "Data Source=xxx\SQLEXPRESS2;" & _
       "Initial Catalog=db;" & _
       "User Id=sa;" & _
       "Password=xxx"
MyConn.Open

st1 = 5
 MyConn.Execute("INSERT INTO steen (steen1) VALUES (st1)")

MyConn.Close
```

However, I'm getting the error: Invalid column name 'st1'.
I have no idea why I'm getting this erro.
When I change the query to this:

```
INSERT INTO steen (steen1) VALUES (5)
```

It works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
MyConn.Execute("INSERT INTO steen (steen1) VALUES ("& st1 & ")")
```

Or:

```
st1 = 5
 Dim StrQuery As String
StrQuery = "INSERT INTO steen (steen1) VALUES ("& st1 & ")"


MyConn.Execute(StrQuery)
```